# How can I go about building Licode sources for use in Android JNI?

Tags: android, android-ndk, licode

How can I go about building [Licode](https://github.com/lynckia/licode) sources for use in Android JNI?

I was hoping to build Licode to build it to the various Android ABIs : armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, and x86-64.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Where did you get stuck?

Comment: The native components seem to have conanfiles and CMakeLists.txt, so you could give it a go with the packaged [CMake toolchain files](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cmake#command-line)